# WordPress - Custom user role - grant guest access to edit.php without insert/update/delete

Tags: php, database, wordpress, permissions, roles

I am working on a site where I want to show customers a demo-version of a product.
To do this they can login with a guest-account, I have created this role as follows

```
add_role('guest', __('Guest'), array('read'=> true));
```

When I login as a guest I get redirected to and get to see the `overview-page /admin.php?page=my_overview`, so this does work, but when the guest clicks on any item in this overview I get a message saying: *You don't have permission to access this page.*

These items refer to pages like: `/profile.php /edit.php /users.php /admin.php`
Since using these pages is a basic part of my products functionality, I want to **grant the guest account access to these pages, but don't let them insert/update/delete any data** which is shown on those pages.

I have tried adding multiple different privileges `i.e. edit_posts, edit_private_posts, edit_private_pages, read_private_posts, read_private_pages` but I can't get it to work right.

I would like to achieve this guest account with specific permissions without the use of any plugin. Basically I want to create a user that can do the same as an Author, but without any `INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs` on my demo-site to the database

I don't know if it is even possible, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After adding role , you can use : https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ plugin

Comment: I preferred to go without a plugin, and I think I figured it out by now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, I was only creating a role, but I didn't add any capabilities to it.
The code I was missing will be like and its working now:

```
function add_capability() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'guest' );
    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_post' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_capability');
```